# Jagged black parts of mesh only at certain angles

Tags: shaders, light

I'm not sure how to deal with this issue I'm facing. I'm quite new but I've researched this issue and I've tried deleting doubles (merge by distance) and I've tried to recalculate normals but none of those really work. I was wondering if someone had bumped into a similar issue.

The picture you see are from the same fish. It's only from certain angles it affects but I'm not sure why.. In the rendered part image some parts of the fish turns really dark and those parts look really bad.

Pictures from different angles from cycles render in viewport by just rotating the camera a small bit, not changing anything else.

[image: fish]
[image]